# mySQL update two columns based on a condition

Tags: mysql

My original query looked like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET period = IF(period > 1, period - 1, 13),
      year   = IF(period = 1, year - 1, year)
```

but this query fails because the second part of the SET uses the just set version of period so there's now no records with a period of 1. I'd like to do this in a single query - suggestions?

Comment: if I understand the issue correctly, you could just swap the order of your SET statements. eg: set year first, and then period.

Comment: @CollinDriscoll that in fact works I think. I guess I was also looking for a solution in the abstract; what do you do when you need the "original" value later in an update after you've changed it ... or is there simply no option?

Comment: I think you'd want to use a WHERE clause instead. I know it's not functionally identical, but using those inline IF's seem problematic in this case. `UPDATE myTable set period = period -1, year = year -1 WHERE period = 1` Something like that.

Comment: @just.another.newbie: This is interesting. Maybe the "transaction isolation level" could have an impact? See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html . But I'm just guessing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your goal, but you can just change your second condition to `period=13`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb38/1

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET period = IF(period > 1, period - 1, 13),
      year   = IF(period = 13, year - 1, year)
```